# Haskell Parser Fails on "|" Read

Tags: parsing, haskell, interpreter, parsec

I am working on a parser in Haskell using Parsec. The issue lies in reading in the string `"| "`. When I attempt to read in the following,

```
parseExpr = parseAtom
         -- | ...
         <|> do string "{|"      
                args <- try parseList <|> parseDottedList
                string "| "
                body <- try parseExpr
                string " }"
                return $ List [Atom "lambda", args, body]
```

I get a parse error, the following.

```
Lampas >> {|a b| "a" }
Parse error at "lisp" (line 1, column 12):
unexpected "}"
expecting letter, "\"", digit, "'", "(", "[", "{|" or "."
```

Another failing case is `^` which bears the following.

```
Lampas >> {|a b^ "a" }
Parse error at "lisp" (line 1, column 12):
unexpected "}"
expecting letter, "\"", digit, "'", "(", "[", "{|" or "."
```

However, it works as expected when the string `"| "` is replaced with `"} "`.

```
parseExpr = parseAtom
     -- | ...
     <|> do string "{|"      
            args <- try parseList <|> parseDottedList
            string "} "
            body <- try parseExpr
            string " }"
            return $ List [Atom "lambda", args, body]
```

The following is the REPL behavior with the above modification.

```
Lampas >> {|a b} "a" }
(lambda ("a" "b") ...)
```

So the question is (a) **does pipe have a special behavior in Haskell strings, perhaps only in `<|>` chains?**, and (b) **how is this behavior averted?**.

Comment: What are `parseList` and `parseDottedList` ?

Comment: @Ankur other "read-in" functions, like `char` or `spaces`.

Comment: try changing it with another `char`, one that is not used in the parsing, like `}` that you chose, to see if is Haskell or your grammar

Comment: @chamini2 I got it to work using `} ` rather than `| `, are you saying try another? I know the issue to be with `| ` and `| ` alone.

Comment: try with a `char` that you don't use in your grammar, such as `^` or something like that, because you already use `}` in the grammar, leaving the possibility that the problem is the parser skipping the second `}`

Comment: @chamini2 you're on to something! I got the same behavior.

Comment: which behavior? you posted two, edit your original post with this example

Comment: @chamini2 I did, and I have solved it. If you want to post as an answer that `|` may be in a set of reserved characters (symbols in my parser) for variables etc., the same set as `^`, you'd have the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character `|` may be in a set of reserved characters. Test with other characters, like `^`, and I assume it will fail just as well. The only way around this would probably be to change the set of reserved characters, or the structure of your interpreter.